# Python Tkinter multi choices quiz - change buttons colour to show the correct answer

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a bit of trouble with my quiz Tkinter GUI. It is a multiple choices quiz in which each choice is represented by a tkinter Button (not a ttk Button).

[screenshot of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKNTz.png)

I bind each button to a function click_button which is called when the button is clicked on. The function compares the index of the button to the index of the correct answer. If the button corresponds to the correct answer, its background colour must be changed to green, else it must be changed to red and the correct answer button background colour must be changed to red. Then another function is called which generates a new question and set of responses and update the Label object to display the new question and the buttons to display the new answers with a neutral background colour (white).

My problem is, how can I "pause" the GUI for few seconds after having updated the background colour of the buttons to show the correct answer so that the user can see the correct answer before the whole interface is updated to show the new question?

It seems that using time.sleep() is pausing the whole main thread, so the GUI is paused and the background colour change is not displayed before the new question is displayed.
I tried also a more complex strategy with an auxiliary sleeping thread which is just a thread that sleeps for a given time (3 seconds) and then ends. I tried to run this sleeping thread after performing the background colour update and to join before updating the GUI to display the new question. But apparently, same problem as before.

If anyone has a clue on how to solve this problem, I would be really grateful.

Here's some sample of my code:

The function called when button_2 is clicked on:
'''

```
def click_button_2(self, event):
    print(2)
    if self.right_answer_index == 1:
        self.button_2.config(background = 'green')
        
    elif self.right_answer_index == 0:
        self.button_2.config(background = 'red')
        self.button_1.config(background = 'green')

    elif self.right_answer_index == 2:
        self.button_2.config(background = 'red')
        self.button_3.config(background = 'green')
     
    else:
        self.button_2.config(background = 'red')
        self.button_4.config(background = 'green')
    
    time.sleep(3)
    self.question, self.answers, self.right_answer_index = self.generate_question()
    self.refresh_window()
```

'''

The function which initialises the window and creates the widgets:

'''

```
def initialize_window(self):
    self.main_window = Tk()
    
    self.main_window.title("Music Quizz")
    self.main_window.geometry('500x500')
    
    self.main_frame = Frame(self.main_window)
    self.main_frame.pack()
    
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.main_frame)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.main_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
    
    self.canvas_frame.bind(
                "<Configure>",
                lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                    scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
                )
            )
            
    self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", GUI_music_quizz._on_mousewheel)
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.canvas_frame, anchor = "nw")
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
    self.canvas_frame.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand=True)
    
    
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")      
    self.main_frame.pack(expand=True, fill = BOTH)
    
    self.question_label = Label(self.main_frame, text = '',  width = 60)
    self.question_label.pack(pady=20)
    
    self.button_1 = tk_Button(self.main_frame, text = '', width = 30, height = 5)
    self.button_1.bind('<Button-1>', self.click_button_1)
    self.button_1.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)

    
    self.button_2 = tk_Button(self.main_frame, text = '', width = 30, height = 5)
    self.button_2.bind('<Button-1>', self.click_button_2)
    self.button_2.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)
    
    self.button_3 = tk_Button(self.main_frame, text = '', width = 30, height = 5)
    self.button_3.bind('<Button-1>', self.click_button_3)
    self.button_3.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)
    
    self.button_4 = tk_Button(self.main_frame, text = '', width = 30, height = 5)
    self.button_4.bind('<Button-1>', self.click_button_4)
    self.button_4.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)

    self.refresh_window()
    
    self.main_window.mainloop()
```

'''

The function which displays the new question:

'''

```
def refresh_window(self):
    
        self.question_label.config(text = self.question)
        
        self.button_1.config(background = 'white', text = self.answers[0])
        self.button_2.config(background = 'white', text = self.answers[1])
        self.button_3.config(background = 'white', text = self.answers[2])
        self.button_4.config(background = 'white', text = self.answers[3])
```

'''

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried simply delaying the call to `refresh_window` using `after`?

Comment: Simply call `self.main_window.update()` before the `time.sleep(3)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, both solutions worked well on this problem. I wasn't aware of the existence of those functions. Thanks for your help :)